# "Break" a While Loop in ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, loops, while-loop

I'm using the following code to output entries from my database:

```
  while(reader.Read()) 

  { 
      Label1.Text += "<div>" + reader["Title"] + "</div>";

  }
```

However, I'd like for every 2nd entry for a "class" to be added to my div.

So ultimately, my HTML could look like:

```
<div>Title1</div>
<div class="two">Title2</div>
<div>Title3</div>
<div class="two">Title4</div>
...
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

Just have a counter, and for every odd number change `<div>` to `<div class="two">`

```
int count;
while(reader.Read()) 
{
  Label1.Text += (count % 2 == 0 ? "<div>" : "<div class=\"two\">") + 
       reader["Title"] + "</div>";
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I tried it and it worked perfectly :) Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The simple way is to just use a quick boolean value to determine whether to add the class or not:

```
bool useClass = true;

while(reader.Read()) 

      { 
          useClass = !useClass;
          Label1.Text += (useClass)? "<div class=\"alt\">" : "<div>";
          Label1.Text += reader["Title"] + "</div>";

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter, then add 1 every time through the loop. Use the mod operator to add class every other time.

```
int i = 0;
while(reader.Read())
{
    if(i % 2 == 0) 
    { 
        Label1.Text += "<div>" + reader["Title"] + "</div>";
    }
    else 
    { 
        Label1.Text += "<div class=\"two\">" + reader["Title"] + "</div>";
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nate. Looks very nice and simple. Hope to use this solution.

Comment: Many of the other answers are the same, they simply are using syntactic sugar to spoil readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
while(reader.Read())
{
    bool addClass = (++index % 2 == 0);
    Label1.Text += (addClass ? "<div class=\"two\">" : "<div>") + 
       reader["Title"] + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm away from the computer right now to test this, but it looks perfect. Thanks for taking the time to help out :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be 2, you don't need to bother with math operations of mod and increment. You can simply use a boolean:

```
bool useTwo = false;

while(reader.Read())
{
    Label1.Text += (useTwo ? "<div class=\"two\">" : "<div>") + 
                    reader["Title"] + "</div>";
    useTwo = !useTwo;
}
```

This just creates a quick toggle that doesn't build up. Granted the math cycles are pretty miniscule, but it all adds up in the end.